# Passing a function as a parameter

Tags: php

I don't know if this is possible but I would like to call a function within a function by passing the function as a parameter, for example...

```
timeThis(test());

function test(){
   $i = 0;
   echo "add 1";
   $i += 1;
   echo "minus 10";
   $i -= l0;
}

function timeThis($fun){
   $timer = new timer;
   $timer->start();
   $fun;
   $timer->pause();
   echo $timer->get();
}
```

Is something like this possible in php? regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (in PHP 5.4):

```
function timeThis(callable $fun){
   ...
   $fun();
   ...
}
```

Usage:

```
$var = function () { ... }
timeThis($a);
```

Or you can call a function by string:

```
function aFunc() { ... }
call_user_func('aFunc');
```

Comment: callable only exists since PHP 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @bizzehdee: in that case, "Closure" should work as the type hint at least in 5.3.10.  But with the standard being "callable" in 5.4, it might not be easy to maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

this works on all versions of PHP5. you could use "callable", but that limits you to php5.4 i believe.

```
timeThis('test');

function test(){
   $i = 0;
   echo "add 1";
   $i += 1;
   echo "minus 10";
   $i -= l0;
}

function timeThis($fun){
   $timer = new timer;
   $timer->start();
   $fun();
   //or
   call_user_func($fun);
   $timer->pause();
   echo $timer->get();
}
```

Comment: `call_user_func('fun');` returns the error `PHP Warning:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'fun' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: sorry, made the correction. should have been $fun and not 'fun'